# foreach loop still echoes array

Tags: php, functions, array

I'm not sure why the foreach loop is still printing an array for my `$education` variable. This code is supposed to get the custom post fields. It works with the title, the image and the about variable, but not when the variable has been put in an array.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'team members', 'posts_per_page' => 40 , 'paged' => 1,);
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  $counter = 1;

  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

      $title = get_the_title();
      $about = get_post_custom_values('about');
      $education = get_post_custom_values('education');
      $certications = get_post_custom_values('certications');
      $image_upload = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'profile_image', true); // CALL IMAGE
        echo '<div class="tab blue black '. join( ' ', get_post_class() ) .'"><input id="inputnumber' . $counter . '" type="checkbox" name="group1" class="trigger"><label for="inputnumber' . $counter . '">' . $title . '</label> <span class="content">' . $about[0] . '</span></div>';
      foreach($education as $value) {
      echo $value; // Displays "12" (there are 12 tracks on this album)
  }
    echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_upload);  // Echo image

    endwhile;

  ?>
```

UPDATE: vardump prints the number of populated rows, but not the actual content of these rows. The custom field I am trying to call is a small table with content.

Comment: `echo "$value";` I think    `echo $value;`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't do the trick, but I think you're right about it needing no quotes - thanks. EDIT: updated above code

Comment: Try `foreach($education as $key => $value)` so you're not echoing the keys.

Comment: still nothing - just the array numbers. :(

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear.  Is the problem that the output is an array instead of a single value?

Comment: Try: `foreach($education as $key => $value){echo $value }`; possibly do a `var_dump($education)` before the cycle, to see exactly what's in there

Comment: Yeah @jdm2112, so all it outputs is a number, but not the actual content/string

Comment: Have you looked in the database to see what is actually in the metavalues?  What is the actual content/string you are expecting to see?   Are the education 'numbers' lookup values to an education table somewhere that has the descriptions?

Comment: Also, your question is a little confusing.  In your code, the 'about' and the 'education', 'certification' are probably returning arrays, whereas image and title would not be. Note that get_post_custom_values does return an array. 
Get post meta if using 'true' as 3rd parameter will expect to fetch just a single value. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/.   So it sounds like the data is being queried correctly, but you are not seeing the results you expected.  As per earlier comment check the data structure.

Comment: Further to that, your `$education` var is the array and I'm sure if you do a `var_dump( $education )` you'll see it as `$key => $value` pairs.

Comment: @jdm2112 well, yes, it is. That's why he uses foreach loop to display the vaslues, but he's always getting 12 (size of array) instead - that's what I'm guessing is the problem in here...

Comment: Yeah so a vardump returns things like "array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" }"

Comment: OK, so now I have realised that it prints the number of lines used in the custom field column.

Just to recap: I have a custom field type (table) and trying to display the contents on my page. The code currently displays the number of rows, not the content.

Comment: After further research I believe I may have to call the sub_field in order to display all the content?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is what I did wrong.

This was an array within an array, which meant that I had to use the element index to echo the values. I'm not even sure I'm explaining it right, but thanks for your help all. It's working now.